# Parse xml file in android ,fetch all attibutes of given node

Tags: java, android, xml, dom, sax

I am trying to get the `id`, `name` and `pin` from the below posted `xml` file and i wrote the below posted code. 
Problem is, this line `node.getNodeValue()` return always null

please let me know how to get the `id`, `name` and `pin` from the `xml` file correctly?

**code**

```
try {
            URL url = new URL(link);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(conn.getInputStream());

            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("employee");

            Log.i(TAG, " nodeLength:" + nodes.getLength());


            for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i ++) {
                Node node = nodes.item(i);
                Log.i(TAG, "Current Element :" + node.getNodeValue());//THIS LINE
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**xml**

```
<employee_list>
<employee id="21358" pin="0000" name="www"/>
<employee id="21359" pin="0011" name="qqq"/>
<employee id="20752" pin="1011" name="Test"/>
<employee id="814" pin="1012" name="Pf"/>
<employee id="21372" pin="1013" name="Kru"/>
</employee_list>
```

**stack trace**

```
01-24 15:05:54.219 5624-5718/com.example. I/XmlParser:  nodeLength:33
01-24 15:05:54.220 5624-5718/com.example. I/XmlParser: Current Element :null
01-24 15:05:54.220 5624-5718/com.example. I/XmlParser: Current Element :null
01-24 15:05:54.220 5624-5718/com.example. I/XmlParser: Current Element :null
01-24 15:05:54.220 5624-5718/com.example.I/XmlParser: Current Element :null
01-24 15:05:54.220 5624-5718/com.example. I/XmlParser: Current Element :null
```

Comment: post stacktrace

Comment: @Rasi posted please have a look

Comment: try this `node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("id").getNodeValue()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fetch the `NamedNodeMap` of all `Attributes` and use `getNamedItem` with  `Id,pin,name` as key to this function and finally fetch the value using `getNodeValue` function

```
     NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("employee");
     for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i ++) {
         Node node = nodes.item(i);
         NamedNodeMap attr =  node.getAttributes();

         // find item using key name and then fetch the node value
         String id = attr.getNamedItem("id").getNodeValue();
         String pin = attr.getNamedItem("pin").getNodeValue();
         String name = attr.getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue();    
         System.out.println(id+" "+pin+" "+name);
     }
```

Output :

```
21358 0000 www
21359 0011 qqq
20752 1011 Test
814 1012 Pf
21372 1013 Kru
```

or you can also use the loop instead of fetching single values

```
     NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("employee");
     for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i ++) {
         Node node = nodes.item(i);
         NamedNodeMap attr =  node.getAttributes();
         for(int j = 0 ; j<attr.getLength() ; j++) {
             Attr attribute = (Attr)attr.item(j);     
             System.out.println("Current Element :" + attribute.getName()+" = "+attribute.getValue());
          } 
     }
```

Comment: how to get the child node and its attribute value say if i have xml like below :

 <ALLOWANCES_FORM sendTableEditEvent="false" sendSelectionEvent="true">
        <RESULT multiSelect="false">
          <field header="Category" size="75" align="left" edit="false"/>
          <field header="Allowance" size="-1" align="left" edit="false"/>
        </RESULT>
      </ALLOWANCES_FORM>

Comment: @JerryAbraham use `((Element)doc.getElementsByTagName("RESULT").item(0)).getElementsByTagName("field");` this will give you the `NodeList` object so use loop (as shown in above answer) and travel through it while apply thing casting to fetch the attributes